# How to get ionic rootScope on config stateprovider?

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

How to retrieve `$rootScope` value in line below?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {  
  $stateProvider
  // Here is where I need to get the value of $rootScope.
}
```

Comment: In `config`(configuration) phase `$rooScope`(scope) of application haven't been created, so you can't get `$rootScope` there, you could use `.run` block where you can inject & use `$rootScope`

Comment: would you give an example for that..? thank you

Comment: `.run(function($rootScope){
   /* use $rootScope here */
})`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used the ionic popup service in config module

Inject $ionicPopupProvider in your config function

After that do something like this

```
 $ionicPopupProvider.$get().alert({
                  title: 'Alert',
                  template: "Something went wrong on Server Side"
                });
```

The same can be used for rootscope also,inject rootScopeProvider and use it